# Odoo v9: choose view for "create and edit"

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm using Odoo 9.

How can I set the view used when the user clicks on  "create and edit" in a Many2one field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create new view for model. Here example for *crm.team*:

```
<record id="test_my" model="ir.ui.view">
     <field name="name">my.module.form</field>
     <field name="model">crm.team</field>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
         <form>
             <field name="name"/>
         </form>
     </field>
</record>
```

And set id of view using *context*:

```
<!-- many2one field -->
<field name="team_id" context="{'form_view_ref':'my_module.test_my'}"/>
```